# php curl request returns nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

i am using codeigniter and my code is as follows :

**Controller :**

```
    $json_string = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $user_addr . '&destination=' . $vendor_city .'&mode=Montreal';

    $json = $this->curl_get_contents($json_string);


    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    $this->load->view('get_direction_pg',$obj);

public function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if ($ch == FALSE) {
        return array('error' =>"failed");
    }else{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result;
    }


}
```

and it if  i access `var_dump($routes);`

it says,

> undefined variable routes.

Comment: did you try using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);`

Comment: Try to echo the generated URL . And then copy the url and open in a browser new tab..
check if you get any result or not..IF you get any result then there is a problem in the curl call.You can take help of [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: Why `var_dump($routes); `? Obviously `$routes` will not be defined, you do not define it in the code, so where should it come from?

Comment: can you please post an example of $url before executing curl_init?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Sir%20Syed%20Road,%20Karachi,%20Pakistan&destination=karachi&mode=Montreal                                                                                             link works when i place it in browser url but not working with curl function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this: i.e. encoding the vars - before putting into url

```
$json_string = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . urlencode($user_addr) . '&destination=' . urlencode($vendor_city) .'&mode=Montreal';
```

the parameters should be encoded for url, otherwise it is being invalid, and hence you are getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if ($ch == FALSE) {
        return array('error' =>"failed");
    }
    else
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this output now : Error 400 (Bad Request). Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know. what i do now?